# How can i dynamically load captcha in form using PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to load captcha using ajax.
Here what i have:

```
   <h:form>
         <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>  

        <h:panelGroup id="test">
            <!--<p:button rendered="#{testBean.value gt 3}" value="hello" />-->
            <p:captcha rendered="#{testBean.value gt 3}"/> 
        </h:panelGroup>

         <p:commandButton value="TestButton" action="#{testBean.inc()}">
            <f:ajax render="test"/>
        </p:commandButton>

    </h:form>
```

Here is TestBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void inc(){
        value++;
    }
}
```

This is working for simple component like button (commented), but when i trying to load captcha i get error:"**malformedXML: A network error occured**." in my browser.
Is it possible "insert" captcha in form dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with primefaces `p:captcha`